# Python program using numpy and Scipy to calculate triple integration?

Tags: python, scipy

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

def f(x,z):
      return (3*x**2 + 3*z**2)**0.5

def limits_y(x,z):
     return [(2*x**2+2*z**2),8]

def limits_z():
    return [0,2*np.pi]

def limits_x():
   return [0,2]

integrate.nquad(f,[limits_y,limits_z,limits_x])
```

This is my program...after writing this it was showing error:

```
" limits_z takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given "
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that you have two options for `limits_z` (and all other limits)

1. pass a tuple `(start, end)`
2. pass a callable (as you do). if you pass a callable, *it will be called with all integration parameters*. That's what the function does, and since your `limit_z` function does not accept arguments, you get an error

So, the easiest would be to make it a variable

```
limits_z = [0,2*np.pi]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function signatures are incorrect. `f` wants three and `limits_z` wants one parameter. [nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html)

I added an unused parameter called `dump`.

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

def f(x,z,dump):
      return (3*x**2 + 3*z**2)**0.5

def limits_y(x,z):
     return [(2*x**2+2*z**2),8]

def limits_z(dump):
    return [0,2*np.pi]

def limits_x():
   return [0,2]

print(integrate.nquad(f,[limits_y,limits_z,limits_x]))
```

Comment: But , sir, why did we use three parameters (x,z,dump) when we are returning the equation ,i.e., (3*x"*2+3*z**2) with only two variables ,i.e., x & z ????

Comment: "If an element of ranges is a callable, then it will be called with all of the integration arguments **available**". the limits of `x0` depend on `x1, x2, ...`, the limits of `x1` depend on `x2, ...` etc otherwise you would have to solve a system of nonlinear equations. look at the second example in the link I posted.

Comment: Sir , plz send the link

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html very bottom and dont call me sir :D